# Player attributes in game center

Tags: objective-c, game-center

I'll make this short and sweet:
I'm looking for an advice about player attributes.
The official guide from apple to player attributes has 4 masks for attributes- but I only need two.

How can I do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `playerAttributes` of your `GKMatchRequest` object to 2.
Then define your roles like this:

```
#define Role_1 0xFFFF0000
#define Role_2 0x0000FFFF
```

For more information go to [Game Kit Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/Matchmaking/Matchmaking.html) (i guess you have already been there).

Comment: Thanks! Marking as the answer.

Comment: How can I access this attribute from the method - (void)matchmakerViewController:(GKMatchmakerViewController *)viewController didFindMatch:(GKMatch *)match ?